# Why can I do this to an immutable `struct`?

Tags: c#, struct, xml-serialization, immutability

Recently I had to serialize a class that contained complex (immutable) structures. I kept failing, until I came up with this (see `ReadXml()`).

Consider the following code:

```
[ImmutableObject(true)]    
public struct Point : IXmlSerializable
{
    readonly int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public Point(Point other)
    {
        this=other;
    }
    public int X { get { return x; } }
    public int Y { get { return y; } }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        // Immutable, right?
        int new_x =0, new_y=0;
        int.TryParse(reader.GetAttribute("X"), out new_x);
        int.TryParse(reader.GetAttribute("Y"), out new_y);
        // But I can change the contents by assigning to 'this'
        this=new Point(new_x, new_y);
    }
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("X", X.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Y", Y.ToString());
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    Point from, to;
    public Foo() { }
    public Foo(Point from, Point to)
    {
        this.from=from;
        this.to=to;
    }
    public Point From { get { return from; } set { from=value; } }
    public Point To { get { return to; } set { to=value; } }
}
```

Which reads in the following xml file correctly.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo>
  <From X="100" Y="30" />
  <To X="45" Y="75" />
</Foo>
```

My question is how is `this=new Point(new_x, new_y);` work when the contents are immutable (`readonly`) keyword? What is stopping me from adding members like

```
    public void Reset()
    {
        this=new Point(0, 0);
    }
    public void Add(Point other)
    {
        this=new Point(x+other.x, y+other.y);
    }
```

which alter the contents of my structure?

```
    {
        Point foo=new Point(10, 15);
        // foo.X=10, foo.Y=15
        Point bar=new Point(foo);   // Clone
        // bar.X=10, bar.Y=15

        foo.Reset();
        // foo.X=0, foo.Y=0

        bar.Add(bar);
        // bar.X=20, bar.Y=30
    }
```

I am glad this functionality exist because it allows me to read/write immutable structures with Xml files, it is just very surprising that it works.

Comment: Structs and classes are not immutable by default, though it is a best practice to make structs immutable.

Comment: hence the `readonly` keyword, private fields and only getters in properties. All, except `ReadXml` which overwrites the fields.

Comment: This is surprising to a lot of people. See http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/07/01/when-is-a-readonly-field-not-readonly/

Comment: @EricLippert great article. Although the field offset, and `out` arguments may raise a flag. Assignment to `this` directly is actually of great benefit to the programmer. I am glad it is there, yet just a little surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is stopping you from writing `Reset`. In-fact, it will work without an issue.

It's possible with the readonly keyword, because you're actually creating a *new* struct, you're not modifying the original one.

Here's the code and generated IL:

```
public void Reset()
{
    this = new Point(0,0);
}

IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  newobj      UserQuery+Point..ctor
IL_0009:  stobj       UserQuery.Point
IL_000E:  ret
```

Note the `newobj` call.

As [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) puts it: [Basically, “readonly” fields in a struct are the moral equivalent of the struct author writing a cheque without having the funds to back it.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two/)

Comment: So the struct is atomic and immutable. You can change either nothing or all if it has the `readonly` keyword.

Comment: The link in my blog article to the article that actually explains the situation, that link is broken. The article can be found here: http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/07/01/when-is-a-readonly-field-not-readonly/